# Divisible elements in the cohomology of Milnor $K$-theory

Tags: etale-cohomology, algebraic-k-theory, l-adic-sheaves

As a consequence of the strong Tate conjecture over finite fields one can deduce (see [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9801017.pdf) proposition 8.20) for every smooth variety $X$ over a finite field:
$$H_{cont}^i(X,\mathbb{Q}_l(n))=H_{Zar}^{i-n}(X,\mathcal{K}_n^M)\otimes \mathbb{Q}_l\oplus H_{Zar}^{i-n-1}(X,\mathcal{K}_n^M)\otimes \mathbb{Q}_l$$
Here $H_{cont}^i(X,\mathbb{Q}_l(n))$ is the continuous etale cohomology with respect to the inverse system given by $\mu_{l^k}^{\otimes n}$ for different $k$s, tensored with rationals. The sheaf $\mathcal{K}_n^M$ is the $n$-th Milnor $K$-theory sheaf.

A quick comparison implies that since $H_{cont}^i(X,\mathbb{Z}_l(n))$ does not contain infinitely $l$-divisible elements (see [here](https://epub.uni-regensburg.de/26684/1/jannsen12.pdf) Cor 4.9), then any infinitely $l$-divisible element in $H_{Zar}^{i}(X,\mathcal{K}_n^M)$ is torsion. I was wondering whether this is something one can prove (without the assumption of Tate's conjecture)? Even for $n=1$ the Milnor $K$-theory sheaf seems to coincide with $\mathbb{G}_m$, I'm not sure how to deduce the result.

Comment: You may have a look at Geisser's paper on this subject: https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0404425.pdf In particular, Prop. 7.4 gives rather concrete and mostly unconditional computations for $n=1$.